# Dual monitor Support Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: monitor, 18.10

I just installed Ubuntu 18.10 And the dual monitors sport supposed to be in the devices to turn it on. I follow online and they always say go to settings and then devices but I only have System settings. Can’t find the devices? The monitor works it comes up with a light gray screen and I can move my cursor on it but no windows.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try going to System Settings, then Displays.
In the Displays, see if the first and second monitors are showing up.
If both monitors are shown, maybe each of them need to be toggled on to be used.

Or maybe Ubuntu is extending the workspace and the expectation is to mirror the workspace. See if "Mirror displays" is checked off in the Displays interface.